# Color points by their occurrence count in ggplot2 geom_count

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I want to color the points drawn by ggplot2's `geom_count` based on their count.

This is what I have so far:

```
ggplot(test3, aes(eleStart, eleLength)) +  geom_count(aes(alpha=0.25, color= ..prop..)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(0,130,5)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,114)) +
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

Now I basically just want to exchange the `color=..prop..` with the actual count calculated by `geom_count`, not their proportion.

test3 dataframe looks like:

```
# A tibble: 294 x 2
# Groups:   X1 [56]
eleStart eleLength
<int>     <int>
1        0         3
2        0         6
3        0         7
4        0         9
5        0        11
6        0        23
7        0        25
8        0        26
9        0        26
10       0        26
# ... with 284 more rows
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can color points by their occurance with count transformation in `aes`. See the follow example:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, carb)) + geom_count(aes(color = after_stat(n)))
```

[image]

---

If you want to "combine the 2 legends into one legend with colorized points", try the following:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, carb)) +
    geom_count(aes(color = after_stat(n), size = after_stat(n))) +
    guides(color = 'legend')
```

[image]

Color was displayed as colorbar by default. Here, `guides(color = 'legend')` tells `ggplot` to dispaly it as `legend` instead of a seperate `colorbar`.

---

To know more about how to control aesthetic evaluation, see: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_eval.html

Edited on Mar 21, 2023

Comment: Thanks, a quick follow up question, is it possible to combine the 2 legends into one legend with colorized points?

Comment: is it possible to rescale ..n..?

Comment: @HermanToothrot, Sure, you can apply a function to `..n..`. For example, you can use `sqrt(..n..)` instead.

Comment: I know that posts are quiet old - but can somehow explain to be ..n.. or where I can read more about that structure/operator?

Comment: @Lukas, see https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_eval.html for new approaches. I may update this answer later.

Comment: Note for anyone coming in the future:Warning message:
The dot-dot notation (`..n..`) was deprecated in ggplot2 3.4.0.
ℹ Please use `after_stat(n)` instead.

Answer (score 3):

If you examine the help file for the `geom_count` function: `help(geom_count)`, you will see a list of its Computed variables.

> Computed variables
>
> n
>
> number of observations at position
>
> prop
>
> percent of points in that panel at that position

So you can use `geom_count(aes(alpha=0.25, color= ..n..))` to color by the number of observations at a position and `geom_count(aes(alpha=0.25, color= ..prop..))` to color by the percent of points at that position.